# Unable to publish sensor_msgs/IMU message properly

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rosserial to transmit gyroscope values into ROS. I am initializing the message using the format I found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12782/rosserial_arduino-cant-send-a-sensor_msgsimu-msg/). At first I got an error saying the buffer was too small, so I changed the ATMEGA328P field in ros.h from "25, 25, 280, 280" to "5, 5, 512, 512".

This worked, but then I started getting errors like:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428333648.941214] wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[WARN] [WallTime: 1428333651.605690] Serial Port read returned short (expected 1 bytes, received 0 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1428333651.608523] Serial Port read failure: 
[WARN] [WallTime: 1428333651.626828] Serial Port read returned short (expected 8 bytes, received 1 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1428333651.629609] Serial Port read failure: 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428333651.633695] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428333651.636200] msg len is 8
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428333651.646104] wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428333653.732366] wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[WARN] [WallTime: 1428333657.162546] Serial Port read returned short (expected 8 bytes, received 5 instead).
```

From google searches, the only possible explanation I could find was to change the baud rate, however I must not have implemented it correctly as it this resulted in the error (yes, its supposed to be ttyUSB1):

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1428335580.534810] Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB1 at 115200 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1428335598.989444] Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

I am unsure of what to try next. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#define pi 3.14159265359

#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;

ros::Publisher gyro("/imu/data", &imu_msg);

int gyroPin = 0;               //Gyro is connected to analog pin 0
float gyroVoltage = 5;         //Gyro is running at 5V
float gyroZeroVoltage = 2.5;   //Gyro is zeroed at 2.5V
float gyroSensitivity = .0125;  //Our example gyro is 12.5mV/deg/sec
float rotationThreshold = 1;   //Minimum deg/sec to keep track of - helps with gyro drifting

float currentAngle = 0;          //Keep track of our current angle


void setup()
{
  //nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200); //or what ever baud you want
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(gyro);
  imu_msg.header.frame_id = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation.x = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.y = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.z = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.w = 0.0;
}

void loop()
{
  //This line converts the 0-1023 signal to 0-5V
  float gyroRate = (analogRead(gyroPin) * gyroVoltage) / 1023;

  //This line finds the voltage offset from sitting still
  gyroRate -= gyroZeroVoltage;

  //This line divides the voltage we found by the gyro's sensitivity
  gyroRate /= gyroSensitivity;

  //Ignore the gyro if our angular velocity does not meet our threshold
  if (gyroRate >= rotationThreshold || gyroRate <= -rotationThreshold) {
    //This line divides the value by 100 since we are running in a 10ms loop (1000ms/10ms)
    gyroRate /= 100;
    currentAngle += gyroRate;
  }

  //Keep our angle between 0-359 degrees
  if (currentAngle < 0)
    currentAngle += 360;
  else if (currentAngle > 359)
    currentAngle -= 360;
    
  currentAngle = currentAngle * (pi/180);  //convert degrees/s to radians/s
  
  imu_msg.orientation.z = currentAngle;
  
  imu_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
  gyro.publish( &imu_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206700/unable-to-publish-sensor_msgs/imu-message-properly/) by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After messing around with the buffer parameters for a while, I was not able to publish an IMU message directly from the Arduino.

An alternative solution is to publish the data with a different message type, then subscribe to it from the computer. In the same node a publisher can be set up which transmits an IMU message.

---

Originally posted by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) with karma: 38 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-10-26**:
Hi, may I know your detail solution to solve your problem?